# Javascript HTML Redirect

Tags: javascript, html

Code Purpose Question

I am trying to determine the purpose of the line:
    window.location = "https://google.com";

```
<<!-- For IE <= 9 -->
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "https://google.com";
</script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- For IE > 9 -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {
        window.location = "http://bobabend.com/index-old-as-of-3-7-2019.html";
    }
```

Comment: Honestly, this whole code is awful. That line is part of the "comments" that will still run for IE versions 9 and below, as an exploit of IE's terrible parsing. If you don't need to support IE9 and earlier (which, God help you if you do), you can remove that entire section.

Comment: Can you read the comment? `<<!-- For IE <= 9 -->`

Answer (score 1):

If browser is IE 9 or earlier, it will redirect to "google.com"

Comment: IE9 or earlier **